# Android getting no activity error when Mobile Data modem connected first time

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am developing an app that contains an Activity with two fragments. I am using SherlockActionbar and SherlockFragments.
My issue is when I start my app before having connected the mobile Data Modem when I switch on my device the app crashes with the following error. Otherwise the app runs normally and never crashes.
This is the logcat when it happends:

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1091)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1887)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleMessage(FragmentActivity.java:96)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**What effect has that the Mobile Connection turns on?**

I think it happens because the device needs memory and it closes the activity but it's rare. Because I use the debug option that destroys the activities and it works fine.

I think the problem isn't normal. Some of the code of the fragments :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){


        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.news2_list_list);
        headerView = (LinearLayout)myView.findViewById(R.id.news2_header);
        header = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_header, headerView, false);
        headerView.addView(header);


        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            loadSavedInstanceStateInfo(savedInstanceState);
        }else{
            news_shown = new ArrayList<N1>();

        }
        news_list = ItemsDBC.getLastN1ItemsForEachService();
        filter(news_shown, news_list, filter);
        i_adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),news_shown);

        selectCurrentTab(filter);

        initializeList();


        return myView;


    }
```

Thank's for all.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the source code of the class which produces this error.

Comment: I think it happens in a fragment, because they use a reference to the activity. But the issue is to know why, when the data connection switches on, the fragment loses the reference. The only possibility is  because the activity is recreated. What effect can have that the connection switches on?

Comment: @ezefire without code you will not get correct solution. So do post the code also .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was because when the device gets connection with the SIM, the activity receives a configurationChange event like when device is rotated and it makes to recreate the activity.

A "solution" was to capture that event in the manifest like this for the activity:

```
android:configChanges="mnc|mcc"
```

if you want to know what are **mnc** and **mcc**

mnc : Mobile Network Code

mcc : Mobile Country Code

[Got from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

This solution isn't the best one but it works.

The real solution was that in an activity I was calling **super.onResume** in the onPuase. But it was my issue. The other solution could help others.